# Is ELL active due to its large number of questions?

Tags: discussion, views

I realised that most questions get a few views quite quickly, but most do not get much views, but quite a few questions **do** get a lot of views, is it just because the question is on the Hot Network Questions Page, or due to the question being frequently searched up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If it's a 'young' question, only a few days old, and has more than, say, 300 views, like [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/313539/18673), it's a Hot Network Question. You can verify if this happened (since [March 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/295232)) via the [timeline](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/313539/timeline#history_2ee0787d-61ee-4bb5-aaaa-e8140f72809d) or the [revision history](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/313539/revisions#rev-body-1e2d89de-24ba-4335-baa3-c40e1ef35b82).

If it's an old question with more than 20k views, like [these ones](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1581287/top-questions-by-views), it's safe to say they are popular because they answer commonly asked questions in search engines. People often don't realize, but over 90% of the Stack Exchange traffic come from anonymous users who end up here via Google or other search engines.